# Intellij GWT Super dev mode shows blank source code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, blank-line

Intellij GWT Super dev mode shows blank source code

A couple months ago I had setup IntelliJ GWT super mode and when I was using the Chrome Dev tool I could see the .java files in the "sources" tab.

Today however, all of the .java files of my project are completely blank, but everything that is not my project (for example package gwtupload.client) I can see just fine.

What can cause this? Is there something I changed code wise without noticing?

My .gwt.xml file is as such:

```
 <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
  <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
  <set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true"/>
  <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>
```

Comment: Did you fix it? You can try out this project (https://github.com/ibaca/rxbreakout-gwt/blob/master/pom.xml), I use IntelliJ but I do not use the GWT run configuration, instead, I use the maven panel, and in the plugin > gwt-maven-plugin I double click the devmode goal. Works perfectly! and works everywhere! Anyways, it should work with intellij run too, just right click on Breakout.gwt.xml and click "Create Breakout" with the GWT icon, activate super dev mode and run, should work too.

Answer (score 0):

For people ending up here. I have downgraded Chrome version to the version of May and now it works like before. I didn't remember that I had updated my chrome